# How can I instal locale prbt.utf8 in heroku?

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, heroku

Locale install in heroku by defaul is en. I have a function in python to convert currency usd to brl using local, but I haven't found any way to install pr-bt.utf8

I have tried `pip`, `apt-get`, `export` but nothing works.
Now I'm trying deploy dokerized app but I don't know how.

```
# https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-locale

$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-locale

# Create a .locales file with pt_BR only

$ git add .
$ git commit -m"locale pt_BR"
$ git push heroku master --force
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you missed [this step](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-locale#configuration):

> Create a `.locales` file at your app's root, with all the locales you need. Example:
>
> ```
> de_DE
> fr_FR
> ```
>
> Commit that file and trigger a new build. The specified locales will be installed by the buildpack.

So, add a `.locales` file containing

```
pt_BR
```

Then commit that file and redeploy.